# CountVectorzier for list of token of a sentence

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list of words (Indeed they are tokenized supervised):

```
data = [['this', 'is', 'my sentence'], ['try'], ...]
```

Now, I want to use `CountVectorizer` on my `data` (each list is a sentence indeed). How can I do that?

As it is obvious, I can't join each word of a sentence as they are tokenized and I want to count each token.

To be more precise, in a regular way, we pass the corpus to the vectorizer likes the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

How should I pass the corpus to the vectorizer in my case?

Comment: a solution near to my work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37872837/3768871

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem with overriding **tokenizer** and **preprocessor**.

try this

```py
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x, preprocessor=lambda x: x)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Then your question is not clear, because in your question you are just asking how to pass your corpus to the vectorizer, not using its all abilities. I think you need to update it.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Your answer can be a possible solution (not the best one maybe).

Comment: @OmG Then you may accept it as the solution, at least till a better one appears.

Answer (score 0):

The function `CountVectorizer` converts a collection of text to token counts. The example takes in a list of words and returns the values you require, but first we created the corpus by joining the words in each list.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

example1 = 'This is the first document.'.split()

data = [['This', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document.'],['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document.']]
corpus = [' '.join(i) for i in data] #create your corpus here

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(X.toarray())
```

**Edited**
If you just want to count the elements in your list and do not want to be returned with the matrix of token counts and features, a `Counter` is what you need.

```
from collections import Counter

data = [['This', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document.'],['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document.']]
counts = [Counter(d) for d in data]

for c in counts:
    print(c)
```

`counts` is a list of `Counters` in a dict format. You can further access the dict by using `c.items()`.

Comment: How to get the vector of each sentence?

Comment: I've explained more the question. please see the update.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But did you read this in my question: "As it is obvious, I can't join each word of a sentence as they are tokenized and I want to count each token." for example, "my sentence" is a token and I want to count it once, and not counting its subwords "a" and "sentence" separately.

Comment: I did, then why are you using `CountVectorizer`? It works on a collection of texts if you apply it to a single word it defeats the purpose. If you want to count your tokenized words, you can still apply a different function on the `data` list.

Comment: I want to vectorize my sentences. Indeed, I want token vectorizer. you know! Hence, I found CountVectorizer near to my work.

Comment: I think maybe the function you are using and your expected outcome might not be the same. Anyways, I updated my answer and hope it helps you out.